# Error on operating GRASS 7.8 and r.avaflow

Tags: raster, error, grass-7.8

I am using GRASS 7.8 and `r.avaflow` training data (https://www.landslidemodels.org/r.avaflow/data.php) to run my first simulation.

When I tried to run this .sh file (with g.region, r.mapcalc, etc.):

```
#Launching r.avaflow 2.4 computational experiments of landslide-reservoir interactions in a computer-generated landscape

cellsize="10"

g.region -d
g.region -a res="$cellsize"

#Generic landscape
r.mapcalc --overwrite "xre_elevx = if(x()<1000,0.0005*pow(x()-1000,2),if(x()>2000,(2000-x())*0.2,0))" #elevation profile in x direction
r.mapcalc --overwrite "xre_elevy = 0.0005*pow(y()-1000,2)" #elevation profile in y direction
r.mapcalc --overwrite "xre_elevr = xre_elevx+xre_elevy" #elevation without dam
r.mapcalc --overwrite "xre_elev = max(xre_elevr,50-0.5*abs(x()-2000))" #elevation with dam (50 m high)

r.mapcalc --overwrite "xre_elevfill = if(x()<2000,max(40,xre_elev),xre_elev)" #elevation with filled reservoir (water level 40 m)
r.mapcalc --overwrite "xre_hrell = xre_elevfill-xre_elev" #height of lake

r.mapcalc --overwrite "xre_hrel1 = 1.0*pow(pow(100,2)-pow(x()-500,2)-pow(y()-1500,2),0.5)" #release height 1
r.mapcalc --overwrite "xre_hrel1 = if(isnull(xre_hrel1)==1,0,xre_hrel1)" #setting undefined raster cells to zero

r.mapcalc --overwrite "xre_hrel2 = 1.0*pow(pow(100,2)-pow(x()-1350,2)-pow(y()-1650,2),0.5)" #release height 2
r.mapcalc --overwrite "xre_hrel2 = if(isnull(xre_hrel2)==1,0,xre_hrel2)" #setting undefined raster cells to zero

r.mapcalc --overwrite "xre_tstart = if(xre_hrel2>0,150,-1)" #start time of landslide 2

r.mapcalc --overwrite "xre_hentrmax = xre_elev-xre_elevr" #maximum depth of entrainment

#Multi-phase model with three phases (solid and fine-solid landslides, fluid reservoir)> and entrainment of dam
r.avaflow prefix=xre_exp1 cellsize="$cellsize" phases=m elevation=xre_elev hrelease1=xre_hrel1 hrelease2=xre_hrel2 hrelease3=xre_hrell trelease=xre_tstart hentrmax1=xre_hentrmax hydrocoords=2600,1000,1000,180 friction=45,25,0,0,0,0,0.0 viscosity=-3,0,2.5,-9999,-3,0 basal=-5.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0 thresholds=0.25,10000,10000,0.01 controls=0,0,0,1,0,0 time=5,300 cfl=0.25,0.001 profile=300,1700,1000,1000,3100,1000

#Multi-phase model with three phases (solid landslide, fine-solid hydrograph release, fluid reservoir) and entrainment of dam
r.avaflow prefix=xre_exp2 cellsize="$cellsize" phases=m elevation=xre_elev hrelease1=xre_hrel2 hrelease3=xre_hrell hentrmax1=xre_hentrmax hydrograph=xre_hydrograph.txt hydrocoords=250,250,100,225,2600,1000,1000,180 friction=45,25,0,0,0,0,0.0 viscosity=-3,0,2.5,5,-3,0 basal=-5.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0 thresholds=0.25,10000,10000,0.01 controls=0,0,0,1,0,0 time=5,300 cfl=0.25,0.001 profile=300,1700,1000,1000,3100,1000

g.region -d
```

I received this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/tphan/.grass7/addons/scripts/r.avaflow", line 8411, in
>
> main()   File "/home/tphan/.grass7/addons/scripts/r.avaflow", line 2568, in main
> grass.run_command("r.avaflow.main")  # executing r.avaflow   File "/usr/local/grass78/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 441, in
> run_command
> return handle_errors(returncode, returncode, args, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/grass78/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 342, in
> handle_errors
> raise CalledModuleError(module=None, code=code, grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None r.avaflow.main
> ended with error Process ended with non-zero return code -11. See
> errors in the (error) output.`

I'm not sure what I did wrong. This is an example from r.avaflow and I just run the script to test the software.